# Crash reports without any stacktrace (Windows 8.1)

Tags: exception, windows-runtime, hockeyapp

I'm really looking for your help people...

I'm currently in a transition of switching from Splunk MINT (previously Bugsense) to HockeyApp for beta distribution and bug reporting of my Windows 8.1 application.

My problem is that I've **several crash reports without any stacktrace** which makes it pretty much impossible to resolve this errors. 
I'm not an expert in this field so I'm curious how is it possible that nearly all of the received crashes include a stacktrace but only a few are without any detailed information. 
Also the exact exception report may vary for the two different Bugreporting frameworks.

A few examples:

#### System.ArgumentException: The paramter is incorrect.

(System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.)

- No stacktrace!
- HockeyApp reports it as "parameter is incorrect" while the Splunk report says "Value does not fall within the expected range".
  It's definitely the same crash since it occurs at the exact same timestamps and for the same devices. I don't get why the reports are different
- Occurs about ~1 every 1000 sessions

#### System.Exception: The operation cannot be completed because the window is being closed.

- Same report on Splunk & HockeyApp
- Minimal stacktrace on Splunk (No stacktrace on HockeyApp):
  1   Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher.RunAsync 
  2   System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback
- Occurs about ~1 every 1000 sessions

#### System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

- No stacktrace!

It seems like there are some reports where only one of the two crashreporting frameworks displays a stacktrace. For others neither does.
Has anybody any idea for the absence of stacktraces at all?

Many thanks for any help in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried asking the community established for each product?

Comment: Yes, I've posted this question there too. I thought maybe somebody over here can help too. Maybe its related to basic understanding how such crashreports are generated and when stacktraces are unavailable in generell.